# Is this an acceptable approach to solving the following problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Why does my approach not work for the following problem?

**PROBLEM**
A man stands on the roof of a building of height $14.6\,\mathrm{m}$ and throws a rock with a velocity of magnitude $32.1\,\mathrm{m/s}$ at an angle of $34.1$∘ above the horizontal. You can ignore air resistance.

**QUESTION**
Find the *Maximum height* reached by said ball.

**SOLUTION**
Assume that I can find a position function in the $y$ direction for such a situation, and the initial velocity for the $y$ can be found (using a $\sin$ function). Is it an acceptable approach to derive the position function, solve the derivative for time when the derivative = 0 ( implying that velocity = 0 at this max point), and plug back in the found value for t into the position function to get the maximum height?

Comment: Hi. This is homework. Please detail your attempts, formulas and calculations included. Someone *may* then have the will to trawl through that.

Comment: My apologies. I don't expect anyone to trawl though this. Let me try to reword it so it doesn't come off that way.

Comment: There we go. My real question isn't "will you solve this", but rather "can I do a problem like this with this method".

Comment: I've made the mistake of taking the maximum height from the roof as the overall maximum height. Did you remember to account for the starting distance from the ground?

Comment: Yes, I accounted for this in my position equation by putting the origin at the base of the tower. Thus, taking it into account in the position equation. Is it correct to assume that the only acceleration on the ball in the y direction is gravity?

Comment: I've never had an issue assuming that before.

Comment: It might work, but you are using 1 equation for 2 variables, which might not work out. Try it yourself. If you want an alternative approach, i can help you

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Question titles are an essential part of a good post. The title of this question contains no useful information for the reader. Please take a look at our [FAQ on writing good question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) and see if you can improve the title of this post :-)

Comment: Thank you all for taking a look at this. I was pretty sure I could do this, but after a through work through mastering physics keeps telling me I'm wrong. Also, I don't understand how this is off topic. I ask a question and ask if my approach was a viable option to solve it, or if there was a better way. That seems pretty concise to me. Also, my work was removed to make this problem more clear. Instead I just listed the approach I used. I imagined this would keep it open to a wider audience.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This approach is definitely viable. Coincidentally, equating the time-derivative of  vertical position to 0 is the same thing as maximising the height mathematically (concept of maxima and minima).

Another approach is to use the conservation of energy. Assume the vertical component of velocity to be $v_y$. Solve it by equating difference of potential energy at topmost and base point in the trajectory to difference in kinetic energy due  to **vertical component** of velocity.

Note: In the second approach, the potential energy If your frame of reference places ground at 0 height(0 potential energy), you won't need to add the height of tower to your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't covered this yet, but I might try to understand it and see if my answer comes out the same.